# Fatal Exception At Startup

Tags: android, layout, widget

I am a beginner writing a simple programmatic UI, and even though I've started over again many times carefully, I can't tell what's breaking this code to the point where it won't even display the UI first. I've got to be doing something wrong with Views, but I can't tell what. Can anybody help?

This is my main activity code (all there is, right now)

```
package com.orbitbreak.musicbox;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.orbitbreak.musicbox.R;

public class MusicBoxActivity extends Activity {

    public ViewGroup viewUpdate;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // makes one image layout
        ImageView singleButton = new ImageView(this);
        singleButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.gridbuttonoff);
        singleButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        viewUpdate.addView(singleButton);

        redrawView(getViewUpdate());

    }

    public void redrawView(ViewGroup param){
        setViewUpdate(param);
        setContentView(getViewUpdate());
    }
    public ViewGroup getViewUpdate(){
        return this.viewUpdate;
    }
    public void setViewUpdate(ViewGroup param){
        this.viewUpdate = param;
    }

}
```

and here's my logcat log

```
02-22 16:53:56.440: D/AndroidRuntime(625): Shutting down VM
02-22 16:53:56.440: W/dalvikvm(625): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015560)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.orbitbreak.musicbox/com.orbitbreak.musicbox.MusicBoxActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     com.orbitbreak.musicbox.MusicBoxActivity.onCreate(MusicBoxActivity.java:25)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-22 16:53:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

**viewUpdate** is null, how did you plan to inflate that view? Is it supposed to be your root view?

You should really consider populating your UI from xml. It's very convenient and the recommended Android way.

**EDIT**

I believe this is exactly what you want: [GridView example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to be the root view. How do I instantiate a ViewGroup like that where I can use .addView(View v) on it?

I started out using XML but for this project I'm making a 16x16 grid of clickable images to be iterated over, so I thought it would be a lot easier to be able to instantiate ImageViews as ImageView[][] elements for processing as opposed to having a unique id for each xml element.

Do you have any advice on how to programmatically generate a grid of a given height/width as xml elements, where I will be able to refer to each element with a variable for onClickListeners?

Comment: if you use xml, you don't have to manually add the views. Try it. You already have specified a layout in xml in your R.layout.main file. In that you can nest children views in viewgroups. alternatively if you insist on putting them programmatically, make sure you put an id on the root view of your R.layout.main file and then do a findViewById on your activity with that Id. That will give you the view which you can use as a parent. Again this is NOT recommended.

Comment: I'm still going to have to redraw the grid with different images as I iterate over it though, having the different imageview elements declare as ImageView[][] array elements is much easier for iterating over them, don't you agree? findViewById takes an integer, there's no way I've seen to convert a loop index to its corresponding imageview xml ID for fast lookup. Can you give me any examples of how to instantiate and manipulate views/setContentView better programmatically? Or XML solutions to my above concerns?

Comment: That looks promising for smaller image collections, but not so great for my purposes. I changed it to source the layout from xml elements again, but new problems have arisen early on in the program flow. Mind taking a look? Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406457/problems-combining-two-activities